# Mails Sent to Specific Domain not Being Received (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I have configured Laravel mail.php file to send mail messages vía smtp using Gmail account (GSuite), it all works fine but there is one detail:

- When sending to an address with a certain domain (in this case, the same domain), the message doesn't
  show up. Even if I send the email through sendmail with whatever address, emails won't show up to those accounts with that specific domain.

I don't know what's wrong but I'm also using this same email address in another web app within the same domain but with no Laravel, instead I'm using PHPMailer and none of those things are happening.

The config file config/mail.php is as follows:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
|            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myaddress@domain.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Store'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'myaddress@domain.com',

'password' => 'MyPassword',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is anti-spam filtering at the remote site.
Rule out other (local) problems first.

1. Have you recived any bounce email messages? [first "warning" usually after 4h]
2. Name your local MTA/SMTP server (sendmail/postfix/exim/...)
3. Provide the relevant MTA/SMTP server log entries.
   The log entries may contain remote server "in SMTP session reject"